# Integer class wrapper performance

Tags: c++, c++11, fixed-point

I am looking to remodel an existing library for fixed point numbers.  Currently the library is just namespaced functions operating on 32-bit signed integers.  I would like to turn this around and create a fixed point class that wraps an integer, but don't want to pay any performance penalty associated with classes for something this fine-grained, as performance is an issue for the use case.

Since the prospective class has such simple data requirements, and no resources, I thought it might be possible to make the class "value oriented", leveraging non-modifying operations and passing instances by value where reasonable.  This will be a simple class if implemented, not part of a hierarchy.

I am wondering if it is possible to write an integer wrapper class in such a way that no real performance penalty is incurred compared to using raw integers.  I am almost confident that this is the case, but don't know enough about the compilation process to just jump into it.

I know that it's said that stl iterators are compiled to simple pointer operations, and would like to do something similar only with integer operations.

The library will be updated to c++11 as a part of a project anyway, so I'm hoping that at least with constexpr and other new features like rvalue references, I can push the performance of this class to near that of pure integer operations.

Additionally, any recommendations for benchmarking performance differences between the two implementations would be appreciated.

Comment: `constexpr` will be useful, I doubt you'll have any use for rvalue references because your class will be so cheap to copy in the first place.  Use lots of inlining, keep your constructors and destructor trivial, and you should see good performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's amusing with this question is that it's just so compiler dependent. Using Clang/LLVM:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline int foo(int a) { return a << 1; }

struct Bar
{
    int a;

    Bar(int x) : a(x) {}

    Bar baz() { return a << 1; }
};

void out(int x) __attribute__ ((noinline));
void out(int x) { cout << x; }

void out(Bar x) __attribute__ ((noinline));
void out(Bar x) { cout << x.a; }

void f1(int x) __attribute ((noinline));
void f1(int x) { out(foo(x)); }

void f2(Bar b) __attribute ((noinline));
void f2(Bar b) { out(b.baz()); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    f1(argc);
    f2(argc);
}
```

Gives [the following IR](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi):

```
define void @_Z3outi(i32 %x) uwtable noinline {
  %1 = tail call %"class.std::basic_ostream"*
                 @_ZNSolsEi(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZSt4cout, i32 %x)
  ret void
}

define void @_Z3out3Bar(i32 %x.coerce) uwtable noinline {
  %1 = tail call %"class.std::basic_ostream"*
                 @_ZNSolsEi(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZSt4cout, i32 %x.coerce)
  ret void
}

define void @_Z2f1i(i32 %x) uwtable noinline {
  %1 = shl i32 %x, 1
  tail call void @_Z3outi(i32 %1)
  ret void
}

define void @_Z2f23Bar(i32 %b.coerce) uwtable noinline {
  %1 = shl i32 %b.coerce, 1
  tail call void @_Z3out3Bar(i32 %1)
  ret void
}
```

And unsurprisingly, the generated assembly is just identical:

```
    .globl  _Z2f1i
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z2f1i,@function
_Z2f1i:                                 # @_Z2f1i
.Ltmp6:
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    addl    %edi, %edi
    jmp _Z3outi                 # TAILCALL
.Ltmp7:
    .size   _Z2f1i, .Ltmp7-_Z2f1i
.Ltmp8:
    .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end2:


    .globl  _Z2f23Bar
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z2f23Bar,@function
_Z2f23Bar:                              # @_Z2f23Bar
.Ltmp9:
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    addl    %edi, %edi
    jmp _Z3out3Bar              # TAILCALL
.Ltmp10:
    .size   _Z2f23Bar, .Ltmp10-_Z2f23Bar
.Ltmp11:
    .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end3:
```

Normally, as long as the methods on the class are inlined, the `this` parameter and references can be omitted easily. I don't quite see how gcc could mess this up.

Comment: "How I learned to stop worrying and trust the compiler", I guess.

Comment: @metatheorem: in general, you should trust the compiler for minute details. For performance, you would better concentrate on your algorithms and I/O (disk, network, database, ...). If the computation is slow, then you will have to profile and check whether it's a CPU or memory bottleneck, and guided by the profiler try to improve there; but it is pretty rare to go down to that level.

Answer (score 1):

impleming fixed point arithmetic with value semantics will yield poorer performance because ...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline int foo(int a) { return a << 1; }

struct Bar
{
    int a;

    Bar(int x) : a(x) {}

    Bar baz() { return a << 1; }
};

void out(int x) __attribute__ ((noinline));
void out(int x) { cout << x; }

void out(Bar x) __attribute__ ((noinline));
void out(Bar x) { cout << x.a; }

void f1(int x) __attribute ((noinline));
void f1(int x) { out(foo(x)); }

void f2(Bar b) __attribute ((noinline));
void f2(Bar b) { out(b.baz()); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    f1(argc);
    f2(argc);
}
```

Now let's see the disassembly of f1 and f2...

```
00000000004006e0 <f1(int)>:
  4006e0:   01 ff                   add    edi,edi
  4006e2:   e9 d9 ff ff ff          jmp    4006c0 <out(int)>
  4006e7:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  4006ee:   00 00 

00000000004006f0 <f2(Bar)>:
  4006f0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  4006f4:   01 ff                   add    edi,edi
  4006f6:   e8 d5 ff ff ff          call   4006d0 <out(Bar)>
  4006fb:   48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  4006ff:   c3                      ret
```

As you can see f2 has some extra messing with the stack pointer which also prevents the ret from being elided.

(This is g++ 4.6.1 at -O3)

Comment: I think you should make your point more explicit with respect to the original question. I guess you mean "impleming fixed point arithmetic with value semantics will yield poorer performance because ..."

Comment: Half the time I see results like this, there is some subtle issue I overlooked (and can often correct, once discovered), rather than just "the compiler doesn't provide as good code as you'd think it would"....

Comment: That's a concise if vague answer, and I got the same result after disassembling and playing with your code.  Any idea what prevents optimization here?

Comment: I wonder how gcc can mess this up. I ran the same code with Clang/LLVM and the produced IR and assembly are just structurally identical.

Comment: Are you sure it was identical?  The noinlines and passing of argc are there for very specific reasons.